# React Modal from Material-UI: Invalid value for prop `className` on <div> tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As the title implies I keep getting this className invalid value, which I assume is from the way i use makeStyles.

Since I'm more used to using "class" and all my other materials on this page are in classes, I also tried to translate the code from https://material-ui.com/components/modal/ to class and ended up with:

```
const modalStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  };

const paperStyle = makeStyles(theme => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
}));
```

And the jsx code:

```
       <Modal
          aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
          className={modalStyle}
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          closeAfterTransition
          BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
          BackdropProps={{
            timeout: 500,
          }}
        >
          <Fade in={this.state.open}>
            <div className={paperStyle}>  <----- ISSUE HERE
            <ItemsTable EBELN_={this.state.clickedEBELN} />
            </div>
          </Fade>
        </Modal>
```

Edit:

Tried to pass as:

```
const paperStyle = makeStyles(theme =>
  createStyles({
    paper:{
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      border: '2px solid #000',
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
      padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
    }
}));
```

And then call at className as: `paperStyle.paper`, the error was gone however it's not using the style at all.

Comment: did u initialize it in your component like the documentation says? `const container = paperStyle();` and then `<div className={container}></div>`

Comment: Yep I tried to do that, got: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Comment: in the documentation it also uses `createStyles` inside the `make Styles`. Also uses a subsection to define class name. Like in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/whfh5)

Comment: Tried it, using the createStyles and passing as paperStyle.paper, the error is gone however it doesn't seem to be using the style at all. Edited post.